# Connecting Local Host to online sql database

Tags: php, sql

I have an online reservation booking system (php script) that uses a mySQL database. Part of the script is a back end admin panel for offline reservations.

Is it possible to run a service like XAMPP using local host to access the remote database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Just the way you connect your local database, you can connect to a remote database with valid credentials. Then only thing changes is the hostname parameter.

for an example if your database is hosted on dreamhost, they have hostnames like..**mysql.yourdomain.com**. Create a database on your remote server and connect to it as

```
<?php
mysql_connect('mysql.yourdomain.com','username','password');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can connect to remote database by having remote host, db username, db password.

Host name = (use the db server IP address)

Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)

Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)

Database password = (***)

MySQL Connection Port = 3306 (check your)

If you are using cPanel then you need to allow your local IP for DB access first.
Login to cpanel, on the main menu of CPanel,
Jump down to "Databases" and select "Remote MySQL"
Now add your IP address, or IP range with a wildcard such as 12.34.%

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need login credentials for the remote database as well as it's port and server address (hostname or IP), as you'd expect. The remote host also needs to have permissions granted for that particular user to access the database remotely, which users will not have by default.

Comment: okay, so the IP name of the website it is hosted on and the port for FTP? Would the permissions be set through the database users table?

Comment: No, the port and host for MySQL. The host name of the database may not be the same as the hostname for your account's web server. For example, if you use GoDaddy, it will be a completely different host name. You can get this information from your hosting provider. Typically the port is 3306 and doesn't have to be specified in code, but that's not something you can assume.